# Coequalizers and kernel pairs

Tags: category-theory

At the best of my possibilities, my question should sound like this. Assume we have a category $C$ in which objects are sets (so I may speak about surjectivity and injectivity of morphisms in the elementary sense) and with small limits and assume we have a pair of morphisms $f,g:a\to b$ in $C$ admitting a common retraction $r:b\to a$. Assume also that they admit a coequalizer $p:b \to c$ and consider the kernel pair $b\times_cb$ of $p$. Then it is clear that there exists a unique morphism $f\times_cg:a\to b\times_cb$ given by the universal property of the kernel pair.

> **Question:** Is $f\times_cg$ surjective?

I know that without the hypothesis on the common retraction, I could not expect this to be true. In Set, for example, the kernel pair of the coequalizer should be the smallest equivalence relation $R$ on $b$ such that $(f(\cdot),g(\cdot))\in R$. But what about in this more particular case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let consider your situation in a category with pullbacks.
Then we have a commutative diagram:

[image]

Since $f$ and $g$ are sections, the comparison morphism ($f\times_cg$ in your notation) $k:a\to b\times_cb$ is a section as well.
Consequently, $k$ is an epimorphism if and only if it's an isomorphism if and only if $f,g$ is the kernel pair of $p$.

[image]

Moreover, since kernel pairs are retractions, $f$ and $g$ are both sections and retractions, hence isomorphisms.
Then $p$ is an isomorphism as well and $f=g$.

Comment: I sincerely beg your pardon, but there is something that does not convince me at all. Consider, in the category of vector spaces over a field $\Bbbk$, an algebra $(A,m,u)$. Then $m: A\otimes A\to A$ is the coequalizer of $A\otimes m,m \otimes A:A\otimes A\otimes A \to A\otimes A$. They admit a common retraction: $A\otimes u \otimes A: A\otimes A\to A\otimes A\otimes A$, but none of them is an isomorphism an, in particular, $m\otimes A \neq A \otimes m$. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I just realized that I used the wrong terminology. Thanks a lot for your effort: I will leave the question here for future reference and ask again the correct question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3467148/reflexive-coequalizers-and-kernel-pairs)