# Reflexive coequalizers and kernel pairs

Tags: category-theory

At the best of my possibilities, my original question should have sound like this. Assume we have a category $C$ in which objects are sets (so I may speak about surjectivity and injectivity of morphisms in the elementary sense) and with small limits and assume we have a pair of morphisms $f,g:a\to b$ in $C$ admitting a common section $s:b\to a$. Assume also that they admit a coequalizer $p:b \to c$ and consider the kernel pair $b\times_cb$ of $p$. Then it is clear that there exists a unique morphism $f\times_cg:a\to b\times_cb$, the comparison morphism, given by the universal property of the kernel pair.

> **Question:** Is $f\times_cg$ surjective?

I know that without the hypothesis on the common section, I could not expect this to be true. In Set, for example, the kernel pair of the coequalizer should be the smallest equivalence relation $R$ on $b$ such that $(f(\cdot),g(\cdot))\in R$. But what about in this more particular case?

Comment: I am sorry if I hurt someone's feeling, I apologize, it was not intended, but could (s)he explain why giving my question a -1 instead of showing me what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no reason for this. In Set, a special case of your question is whether every reflexive relation is an equivalence relation!

Comment: Ok, many thanks for your answer. Please, let me see if I understood your argument. I have a set $X$ and I take a reflexive relation $R\subseteq X\times X$. I consider $\hat{R}$, the smallest equivalence relation containing $R$. Then $\pi:X\to X/\hat{R}$ is the coequalizer of the two obvious projections $p_1,p_2:R\to X$, which admit the diagonal as common section, isn't it? And then asking the comparison morphism to be surjective would tell me that $R=\hat{R}$, which is not true. Is this your point?

Comment: @EnderWiggins Yes, precisely.

Comment: @EnderWiggins It might be worth mentioning that in exact Mal'tsev categories (which includes, in particular, abelian categories), where every reflexive relation *is* a kernel pair, the canonical arrow will indeed be a regular epimorphism.

Comment: @ArnaudD. Thanks a lot for your remark, I didn't know how generally it could be true. In fact, I knew the property to hold for vector spaces, but for other reasons I was wondering if I could use the same argument for sets.